# Using Touchesbegan once

Tags: swift, touchesbegan, touchesmoved

I have a touchesbegan and a touchesmoved that move a UIImageView around the screen. But I want to make it so I can't start moving around the screen then go to the opposite side using touchesbegan. I don't want to be able to just tap my way to other side. Is that even possible? Here's my code:

```
  override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    var touch : UITouch! = touches.anyObject() as UITouch
    location = touch.locationInView(self.view)
    Player.center = location
}
override func touchesMoved(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    var touch : UITouch! = touches.anyObject() as UITouch
    location = touch.locationInView(self.view)
    Player.center = location


}
```

Thanks.